# How can i use placeholder after send buttons to user concurrently

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telethon

In Python Telegram bot i was using this code to make placeholder and replymarkup but I don't see like that in telethon.

```
reply_keyboard = [
        ['test']
    ]
    reply_keyboard_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard=reply_keyboard,one_time_keyboard=True,resize_keyboard=True,input_field_placeholder='pm')
    update.message.reply_text('''test
''',reply_markup = reply_keyboard_markup)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a reply markup in `telethon` nesting lists too, but instead of strings you must storage `telethon.tl.custom.button.Button` instances, check the [documentation here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html?highlight=Button#module-telethon.tl.custom.button) to get a better understanding of `Button` methods.

Building a simple keyboard as the showed in your image:

```py
from telethon import Button

async def handler(event):
    await event.respond(
        'Hello!',
        buttons=Button.text(
            text=' Hello, World!',
            resize=True,
            single_use=True
        )
    )
```

You get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jgM4.png).

I think you cannot mix placeholder with a text keyboard in `telethon`. You can make a placeholder using `Button.force_reply`:

```py
async def handler(event):
    await event.respond(
        'Hello!',
        buttons=Button.force_reply(
            single_use=True,
            placeholder='Say something'
        )
    )
```

This is [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPbLI.png).